# Powering 4.6 V with 5 V USB power supply

Tags: power-supply, voltage, voltage-regulator, dc, dc-dc-converter

I need an output of 4.6V 900mA from 5V USB power supply. The smaller the better, what is the best way to achieve such conversion.

I want to mod Nintendo DSI XL to charge it using USB micro. Case says input power is 4.6 V 900 mA. Google doesn't recognize any ICs near power input so I don't know what's the maximum voltage I can provide (although when I measured the voltage from original power supply (while plugged in) I got 4.8 V).

I tried using these buck converters: [Link](https://solarbotics.com/product/40410/)  but I managed  to fry two of them for no apparent reason, so I don't trust them anymore. Unless you have an idea how I could do it please don't suggest them.

Comment: why are you mixing 4.6 and 4.7 V, why 1A and 900 mA ? Stay with the specifications on the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the device will internally have a regulator to charge the internal battery, it's pretty certain that it can deal with a few percent of overvoltage.

You can certainly try a linear low-dropout regulator (LDO) to regulate the output to 4.7 V, but be aware that at the 900 mA specified, these 0.3 V drop amount to 270 mW of power, which can heat up the regulator significantly.

You could build a higher-efficiency switching regulator, but at output voltages this close to the input voltage, that's a complicated endeavour and I wouldn't recommend it.

The switching regulators that you link to have a maximum duty cycle of 90%, which doesn't allow for conversion of 5 V down to 4.7 V.

Comment: Is that one ok or am I forgetting something: [link](https://uk.farnell.com/texas-instruments/tps73701drvt/ldo-adj-1a-1-2v-5-5v-wson-6/dp/2492514)

Comment: Nothing, but that datasheet says "Junction to ambient thermal resistance 67 °C/W", and you're dissipating about 1/3 of a watt, so expect a temperature increase of > 20 °C. That's pretty benign. Also, WSON is pretty nontrivial to solder, if you've never worked with reflow ovens or a hot-air gun and solder paste. Maybe pick a different package for the same IC.